# Tricky conversion within dataframe using Pandas (compress and de-aggregate)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to compress the columns within my dataframe and de aggregate values:

**Data**

```
state   range   type    Q1 24   Q2 24   stat
NY      up      AA      2       2       grow
NY      up      AA      1       0       re
NY      up      BB      1       1       grow
NY      up      BB      0       0       re
NY      up      DD      2       3       grow
NY      up      DD      0       1       re
CA      low     AA      0       2       grow
CA      low     AA      1       0       re
CA      low     BB      0       1       grow
CA      low     BB      0       0       re
CA      low     DD      0       3       grow
CA      low     DD      1       0       re



dataframe:

import pandas as pd

data = {
    'state': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA'],
    'range': ['up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low'],
    'type': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'DD', 'DD', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'DD', 'DD'],
    'Q1 24': [2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    'Q2 24': [2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0],
    'stat': ['grow', 're', 'grow', 're', 'grow', 're', 'grow', 're', 'grow', 're', 'grow', 're']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Desired**

```
state   qtr     type    range   stat    
NY      Q1 24   AA01    up      grow    
NY      Q1 24   AA02    up      grow    
NY      Q1 24   AA03    up      re  
NY      Q1 24   BB01    up      grow    
NY      Q1 24   DD01    up      grow    
NY      Q1 24   DD02    up      grow    
CA      Q1 24   AA01    low     re  
CA      Q1 24   DD01    low     re  
NY      Q2 24   AA01    up      grow    
NY      Q2 24   AA02    up      grow    
NY      Q2 24   BB01    up      grow    
NY      Q2 24   DD01    up      grow    
NY      Q2 24   DD02    up      grow    
NY      Q2 24   DD03    up      grow    
NY      Q2 24   DD04    up      re  
CA      Q2 24   AA01    low     grow    
CA      Q2 24   AA02    low     grow    
CA      Q2 24   BB01    low     grow    
CA      Q2 24   DD01    low     grow    
CA      Q2 24   DD02    low     grow    
CA      Q2 24   DD03    low     grow
```

**Doing**

```
(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = slice('state', 'type'), 
    names_to = ("qtr", ".value"), 
    names_sep = " ")
)
```

update count

```
newdf=newdf.assign(count=newdf['type']+(newdf.groupby(['state','type'])['type'].cumcount()+1).astype(str))
```

However, this is only once piece, but I am still trying to figure out how to de-aggregate the count. I am researching this. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas.melt) your existing dataframe on the `Q1 24` and `Q2 24` values and then filter out all the rows with a `0` count. You can then use [`index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to make `count` copies of each row. Then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to count the rows per `('state', 'type', 'qtr')` group and use that number to generate a new `type` value:

```py
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['state', 'range', 'type', 'stat'], value_vars=['Q1 24', 'Q2 24'], var_name='qtr', value_name='count')
df2 = df2[df2['count'] > 0]

df2 = df2.loc[df2.index.repeat(df2['count'])]

df2['count'] = df2.groupby(['state', 'type', 'qtr'])['type'].cumcount()+1

df2['type'] = df2[['type', 'count']].apply(lambda r:f"{r['type']}{r['count']:02d}", axis=1)

df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True).drop('count', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   state range  type  stat    qtr
0     NY    up  AA01  grow  Q1 24
1     NY    up  AA02  grow  Q1 24
2     NY    up  AA03    re  Q1 24
3     NY    up  BB01  grow  Q1 24
4     NY    up  DD01  grow  Q1 24
5     NY    up  DD02  grow  Q1 24
6     CA   low  AA01    re  Q1 24
7     CA   low  DD01    re  Q1 24
8     NY    up  AA01  grow  Q2 24
9     NY    up  AA02  grow  Q2 24
10    NY    up  BB01  grow  Q2 24
11    NY    up  DD01  grow  Q2 24
12    NY    up  DD02  grow  Q2 24
13    NY    up  DD03  grow  Q2 24
14    NY    up  DD04    re  Q2 24
15    CA   low  AA01  grow  Q2 24
16    CA   low  AA02  grow  Q2 24
17    CA   low  BB01  grow  Q2 24
18    CA   low  DD01  grow  Q2 24
19    CA   low  DD02  grow  Q2 24
20    CA   low  DD03  grow  Q2 24
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick I will try- I condensed my original dataframe. The original has 4 quarters. Q1 24, Q2 24, Q3 24 and Q4 24- in order to accomodate these, could I simply: 
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['state', 'range', 'type', 'stat'], value_vars=['Q1 24', 'Q2 24','Q3 24', 'Q4 24'], var_name='qtr', value_name='count')

Comment: @Lynn yes, that should be the only change you need

Comment: Hi Nick this almost works - Its just the count seems to be continuous onto the quarters. The counts should start over with each quarter - If you look at NY Q2 24, the AA count starts over and is AA01, not AA04 - wondering how to fix this
Perhaps the qtr needs to be grouped? @Nick

Comment: @Lynn sorry, I missed that. You just need to add `qtr` to the `groupby`. See my edit

Comment: advice for someone trying to get better with Pandas? @Nick - thanks!

Comment: Practice practice practice! :) try answering (or even just looking at answers) some questions on SO - there are lots to make you think about different ways of doing things.

Comment: I especially recommend looking at [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A16343464+%5Bpandas%5D) by @mozway, they are definitely a pandas expert.

Comment: I will certainly do this - yes they are, as is yourself!

Comment: @Nick I would use `Index.repeat` to duplicate the rows, which is more efficient than `apply`+`explode` ;)

Comment: @mozway see, I said you were an expert! :) I'll look at that...

Comment: `df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['count'])]`